# JPA Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean Validation on callback event:'prePersist'

Tags: jpa

Error al tratar de persistir las entidades en `JPA`

> Bean Validation constraint(s) violated while executing Automatic Bean
>   Validation on callback event:'prePersist'. Please refer to embedded
>   ConstraintViolations for details.

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error ocurre cuando se violan las restricciones definidas en la entidad que se `persiste`. Debes validas que los valores que son `NotNull` no se guarden con `null` y cualquier otra restricción definida.

Podrías hacer uso del siguiente código para que te aclare un poco más el error sobre cuál ha sido el problema ocurrido.

Yo hago uso del `AbstracFacade` que se genera en NetBeans, y dentro de este archivo, en los métodos `create` y `edit`, definirlos de la siguiente manera:

```
public void create(T entity) {
    try {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        // Aqui tira los errores de constraint
        for (ConstraintViolation actual : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
            System.out.println(actual.toString());
        }
    }
}

public T edit(T entity) {
    try {
        return getEntityManager().merge(entity);
    } catch (ConstraintViolationException e) {
        // Aqui tira los errores de constraint
        for (ConstraintViolation actual : e.getConstraintViolations()) {
            System.out.println(actual.toString());
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Así, a la hora que ocurre el error de persistencia, en el `log` te mostrará más detalle del error.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo exactamente el mismo error.
Estoy migrando un proyecto java application a un web application con maven.
Todo tiene que ver con el archivo persistence.xml.

En Validation Strategy debes poner None.